# Logging file appender is not able to create file

Tags: unix, logging, file-permissions

I'm getting this error message when logback is trying to create file to log:

```
-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file-appender] - 
   Failed to create parent directories for [/var/log/living/commty/logFile.log]
-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file-appender] - 
    openFile(/var/log/living/commty/logFile.log,true) call failed. 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/living/commty/logFile.log (Permission denied)
```

Nevertheless:

```
ls /var/log/living/commty/ -lha
total 8.0K
drw-r----- 2 wildfly wildfly 4.0K May 23 09:29 .   <<<<<<<<<<<<
drw-r----- 6 wildfly wildfly 4.0K May 23 09:29 ..
```

As you can see `/var/log/living/commty` is `wildfly:wildfly` owned and `rw-r-----` (`read-write` access).

Any ideas?